# Firebase Realtime database suffers high load (greater than 100%)

Tags: performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, we're suffering performance issue in firebase realtime database.

In the firebase console, the load is greater than 100%.

[image: the screenshot of high load]

The below is the description about the high load:
"The percentage of your database that's busy processing requests (either realtime or RESTful) over 15-minute intervals. You may see performance issues as you approach 100%."

Does anyone know what should I do to resolve the issue? Doesn't it support auto-scaling?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a discussion.  It would be more appropriate to ask questions like this on firebase-talk https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk or contact Firebase support https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database indeed does not scale horizontally. Its limits are documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits Typically when you reach 100% usage, it means you're either writing more than documented there, or (less likely) your clients are reading more data than can be pushed out. Use the Firebase Database profiler to get insight into what operations are costly: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile